# Java ProcessBuilder output to create image file

Tags: java, terminal, process, processbuilder

I am currently using ProcessBuilder in java to run a python script as if I was doing it in the terminal. This python script should create an image and in terminal I would do it like this

```
python3 script.py arg1 arg2 > out.png
```

The problem here is that processbuilder does not allow me to add the '>' (redirect the output) char in the arguments followed by the path to my out.png file.

It currently creates an output with strange chars (I assume it is a base64 string).

A bit of my current code:

```
File output = new File("/Users/myuser/Desktop/OUTXXXXXXXXX.png");
ProcessBuilder pb =
    new ProcessBuilder("/usr/local/bin/python3", pythonScriptLocation",
        fileOneLocation, fileTwoLocation);
pb.redirectInput(output);
Process process = pb.inheritIO().start();
int errCode = process.waitFor();
System.out.println("Command executed, any errors? " + (errCode == 0 ? "No" : "Yes"));
```

All variables used above are declared.

Already seen this approach but it did not create any file at all.

EDIT:

With redirectOutput method:

```
File output = new File("/Users/myuser/Desktop/OUTXXXXXXXXX.png");
ProcessBuilder pb =
    new ProcessBuilder("/usr/local/bin/python3", pythonScriptLocation",
        fileOneLocation, fileTwoLocation);

File stdoutFile = new File("/Users/mysuer/Desktop/outxx.png");
pb.redirectOutput(stdoutFile);
Process process = pb.inheritIO().start();
int errCode = process.waitFor();
System.out.println("Command executed, any errors? " + (errCode == 0 ? "No" : "Yes"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop your Java process from inheriting the IO from your Python process (stop calling `pb.inheritIO()`). Once you've done it, you can redirect the output of the process as:

```
File stdoutFile = new File("out.png");
redirectOutput(output);
```

Comment: Tried it just now and it is creating the file but leaving it empty. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Have you tried reading process outputStream and redirecting the output?

Comment: Yes, did so, also tried it but it does not even create me a file.

Comment: Please note that you have to redirect the output, not the input (as in your main code above).

Comment: Yes I did so, I'll update the question with the code for what you are saying.

Comment: I found the problem. Silly me... I was adding the inheritIO() method right before starting the process therefore the redirectOutput would not work. Thank you! I guess you may edit your answer since you actually helped me.

Comment: I was about to tell you that. Glad you found it.